# unable to use two call functions in java

Tags: java, spring, hadoop

Hi In my program there are two imports referring Path.The one path is referring to `web service` `Annotation` and another path refers to `HDFS`. 
But it is conflicting with  one another and `throws` an **error**.

My program.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration ;
@Path("/oozie")
public class RestServiceOozie {
@GET
@Path("/{param}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}")
String arguments = "hdfs://nameservice1/user/ec2-user/" + bedroom + "-" + bathroom + "-" + area + "-" + city;
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
Path path = new Path(arguments); // getting error on this path
if (!fileSystem.exists((org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)path)) {
System.out.println("File does not exists");
}
```

I was getting error on path. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about using the full path?

Comment: that also not working.how to specify full path

Comment: Exactly how it is mention in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fully qualified `{Class|Interface|Annotation}` name if there is an ambiguity. Also, I guess you forget to declare a method in your code.

```
import  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/oozie")
public class RestServiceOozie {

  @GET
  @org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/{param}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}")
  public void fooMethod() {
    String arguments = "hdfs://nameservice1/user/ec2-user/" + bedroom + "-" + bathroom + "-" + area + "-" + city;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path path = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(arguments); // getting error on this path
    if (!fileSystem.exists((org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)path)) {
      System.out.println("File does not exists");
    }
  }
}
```